# Selector for comment when editing

Tags: feature-request, edits, edit-summary

I think it could be a good idea to have a selector instead of a textfield when providing comments after editing a post.

The reason is that (I think) the majority of these edits are either:

- corrected spelling
- fixed grammar
- improved formatting

My idea would be to have a select with these options, and a `custom` option that would display a textfield where the user can enter a custom comment.

[EDIT] could actually be checkboxes. it seems like a good idea. the point is to try to make it a little easier and uniform to add all these comments that are essentially the same.

Comment: So what would I choose if my edit corrects spelling and fixes grammar and improves formatting?

Comment: I removed useless tags and made the title clearer... or maybe I added a tag and removed it from the title... or I fixed a link; I'm not certain yet...

Comment: @YannisRizos: checkboxes?

Comment: These pro forma comments in the edit thingymajig, "fixed grammar" for instance, can be quite annoying. The amount of times I've seen someone whose "fixed spelling" and not bothered to do anything about the rest of the post (or even spelling _everything_ correctly).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Yes, I live for the day when someone checks all boxes for an edit that only fixed a word, or removed whitespace. Let's encourage people to be even more lazy when editing <sigh>

Comment: I see your point

Comment: This would only make things take _longer_ for thsoe of us who fix lots of things and end up with long edit descriptions (e.g. actual description I used recently: "removed title pseudotag; undid title case; made title more descriptive; moved useful text to 'preview space'; minor sp/gr/formatting"). Even for cases where edits _are_ only for spelling and grammar, banging out "sp/gr" doesn't take much longer than using a drop-down list or checkbox would.

Comment: Also, I didn't notice you were new to MSO at first; welcome! FYI, the reason I downvoted you is that I don't want this to be implemented. It's not because your post was unclear or poorly written.

Comment: make sense. these are all valid points. I just had this idea and was wondering what would other people think of it. I have my answer!

Comment: Modern browsers tend to remember your input to specific fields. If you edit frequently, your browser (might) track a history of text that you've entered into that field and offer it as a suggestion on your next edit. I know I rarely need to type anything since my reason tends to pop up as a recently used reason. *Note: dependant on several factors*